# Edittext want to go enable from disable after select the particular item in the spinner items

Tags: android

I'm using Spinner,EditText and Button in one page.The spinner has these items ...

Following:

```
 String[] Items = {
            "Alarm",
            "Office",
            "Meeting",
            "Party",
            "Lunch",
            "Breakfast",
            "Supper",
            "Home",
            "Private",
            "Outdoor",
            "Family",
            "Friends",
            "others"
    };

    Spinner s1;
```

In it if I select the "others" in spinner items means only the Edittext has to be enable otherwise it has to be disabled.If I select some other item Edittext has to be disabled

Code snippet:

```
s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Items);

    s1.setAdapter(adapter);
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, 
        View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
        {
            int index = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                "You have selected item : " + Items[index], 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
    });
```

Thank you,

Comment: your question is not properly explained read your description and make changes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do this,

```
    EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    edit.setEnabled(false);
    edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    edit.setFocusable(false);
```

And when any other option selected do this,

```
    edit.setEnabled(true);
    edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    edit.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: @debar Thanks to ans: sorry repeat this question, will u tell me how to get the value to the items

Comment: cant get you. What do you want to know?

Comment: i got. edittext is going disable, but i don't know how to edittext has to make enable after select "other" in the list.

Comment: I already gave you how to disable and how to enable edit text both,even how to set soft keyboard accordingly. See it and implement it.

Comment: @debarati  editext is going enable after select. but after enable it is not get input ... i can not type in the edittext what problem

Comment: @debarati i finished i used this 'edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);'and'edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);' and it is running so good thank you..

Comment: Yes it'll can't be done in this way. Try it by hideSoftInputFromWindow and toggleSoftInputFromWindow methods. Try it on your own. Then let me know.

Comment: you should `setFocusableInTouchMode` before `setFocusable`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you get the value from the Spinner.

After getting the value using condition u set the edittext enabled or disabled through this code:

```
  EditText.setEnabled(BooleanValue);
```

true is default value and false set the edittext disabled.