# How can I enable editText from popup menu?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, popup, isenabled

I Have a listView of 3 editText, when I displays the data in these editText, I set editText to disabled ,after that I create a popup menu where i have edit item to modify data, so when i click on it I enabled editText.
I tried all the solutions regarding enable / disable edittext .But it's not working. :

[Enable EdittEXT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlFSW.png)

[Enable EditText 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944215/edittext-want-to-go-enable-from-disable-after-select-the-particular-item-in-the)

My screen lisTview :

[image]

Source :

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    final int pos = position;

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

    name = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_book_display);
    statusMsg = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc_display);
    prix = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prix_display);

    disableEditText(name);
    disableEditText(statusMsg);
    disableEditText(prix);



      popupMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            IconizedMenu popup = new IconizedMenu(parent.getContext(), view);
            MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.poupup_menu, popup.getMenu());

            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new IconizedMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                                                 @Override
                                                 public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                                     switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                                         case R.id.update_book:
                                                              enableEditText(name);
                                                             enableEditText(statusMsg);
                                                             enableEditText(prix);
                                                             updateBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                                                             return true;
                                                         case R.id.add_book_to_favoris:
                                                             return true;
                                                         case R.id.delete_book:
                                                             return true;

                                                         default:
                                                             return false;
                                                     }
                                                 }
                                             }


            );

            popup.show();


        }
    });




      return convertView;
}


     private void disableEditText(EditText editText) {
    editText.setFocusable(false);
    editText.setEnabled(false);
    editText.setCursorVisible(false);
    editText.setKeyListener(null);
    editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}


private void enableEditText(EditText editText) {
    editText.setFocusable(true);
    editText.setEnabled(true);
    editText.setCursorVisible(true);
    editText.setKeyListener(listener);
}
```

Update screen debeug :
[image]

Comment: try to log the `disableEditText` and `enableEditText` just to see if they are being called

Comment: @OmarAlHalabi check the update I debug it, they are being called

Answer (score 1):

```
editText.setFocusable(true);
editText.setEnabled(true);
editText.setCursorVisible(true);
editText.setKeyListener(editText.getKeyListener());
```

Comment: its not working , I update the question with the image of one of the fields, Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` instead of `editText.setFocusable(true)`.

Update your `enableEditText()` method as below:

```
private void enableEditText(EditText editText) {
    editText.setEnabled(true);
    editText.setCursorVisible(true);
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
}
```

Comment: Also ,its not working , I update the question with the image of one of the debeug fields , Please check it